# CSS formatting a template to get layout working properly

Tags: html, css, formatting, styles

Hi guys wondering if I could get a little assistance with my site. It is for a uni assignment on e-Business and I have used a template. I have gotten a Javascript code to keep track of amount of items in the basket and cost but I can't get it to display nicely.

It is either on the same line as 'Shopping Cart' or if I use `<br>` goes well below the header menu section.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKMon.png
to give you an idea of what I mean

Code for header.php

```
        <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html">Pet Accessories</a></h1> 

    <!-- Cart -->
    <div id="cart">
        <a href="managecart.html" class="cart-link" >Your Shopping Cart</a>
        <br />
        <script language="javascript" >
            if ( Cart_is_empty()) {
                document.write('Your cart is empty.');
            } else {
                Print_total_products(true);
                document.write(', ');
                Print_total(true);
            }
        </script>

    </div>

    <!-- End Cart -->

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Navigation -->
```

Code for relevant style.css

```
    #header { height:64px; background:url(images/header.gif); position:relative;}
    #navigation { float:right; white-space:nowrap; }
    #navigation ul{ list-style-type: none; height:64px; font-weight: bold; float:left;}
    #navigation ul li{ float:left; display:inline; }
    #navigation ul li a{ float:left; height:64px; line-height:64px; text-decoration: none; color:#fff; padding:0 15px;}
    #navigation ul li a.active,
    #navigation ul li a:hover{ background:#fff; color:#8b0000; }

    #cart { float:right; width:160px; top:0; right:0; height:51px; background:#8b0000; color:#fff; padding:13px 10px 0 10px; white-space:nowrap; line-height:38px;}
    a.cart-link { color:#fff; background:url(images/cart-link.gif) no-repeat 0 0; padding:0 0 0 32px; text-decoration: none;}
    a.cart-link:hover { text-decoration: underline;}

    #sidebar { float:left; width:226px;}
    #content { float:right; width:724px;}

    #main { padding:10px 0 0 0; }
```

I have tried to provide as much information as possible, any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't know if I need to modify the .css file or use another type of `<br>` to get my text to show in right spot.

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: where is the "right spot" you're wanting?

Comment: [Something like this](http://i.imgur.com/WoWQaA0.png) @EdmundJoseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change height in #cart to min-height (and for the rest of the top section for that matter) or remove it completely.

If you must have it at that fixed height, change the line-height in #cart small enough that it will fit.

Comment: Thanks! I just tweaked line-height to 15px and it seems to work fine
[pic](http://i.imgur.com/MvOKJIH.png)

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that my partner had style.css and /css/style.css and I was modifying the wrong one :/

Answer (score 0):

The `#cart` element has a 38px line-height. Remove that.

Another thing you may want to do is remove the `<br />` tag to let them be in the same line.

Note that the 160px width won't be enough. You should make it higher (changing all other elements width too) or remove `white-space:nowrap;` in the `#cart` element.

Comment: Thanks! I just tweaked line-height to 15px and it seems to work fine
[pic](http://i.imgur.com/MvOKJIH.png)